# Only outputting a few lines into a text file, instead of all of them

Tags: python, csv

I've made a Python script that grabs information from a .csv archive, and outputs it into a text file as a list. The original csv file has over 200,000 fields to input and output from, yet when I run my program it only outputs 36 into the .txt file.

Here's the code:

```
import csv
with open('OriginalFile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    emailreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    f = open('text.txt', 'a')
    for row in emailreader:
        f.write(row[1] + "\n")
```

And the text file only lists up to 36 strings. How can I fix this? Is maybe the original csv file too big?

Comment: Without your input and output files, we're in the dark about what could be happening. At the least, check the formatting of your CSV file.

Comment: The csv file is over 230,000 rows long, all info separated by commas per field - the script gathers them and outputs them to the txt file which looks like: https://pastebin.com/L6KzWYev

Comment: Print the first 37 rows here so we can reproduce the error

Comment: The exported txt files looks like that pastebin I linked. While the original csv file are 200,000 rows like this:

john paul,johnpaul@gmail.com,202,909,2016-08-21 11:12:33-

From which I only take out the e-mail

Comment: what's the `value of next input` at which it stops? `I guess you're error is with the input`!!!

Comment: Next input is just the same as the others, but here's the error code PyCharm gives me when running the script:

https://pastebin.com/bfa4prR5

Comment: try: `with open('OriginalFile.csv', 'rb') as csvfile: `

Comment: Please put relevant information, including the pastebin link into the question itself. Comments are for discussion, not for relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many comments, the original problem was encoding of characters in the csv file.  If you specify the encoding in pandas it will read it just fine.

Any time you are dealing with a csv file (or excel, sql or R) I would use Pandas DataFrames for this.  The syntax is shorter and easier to know what is going on.

```
import pandas as pd
csvframe = pd.read_csv('OriginalFile.csv', encoding='utf-8')
with open('text.txt', 'a') as output:
    # I think what you wanted was the 2nd column from each row
    output.write('\n'.join(csvframe.ix[:,1].values))
    # the ix is for index and : is for all the rows and the 1 is only the first column
```

Answer (score -1):

You might have luck with something like the following:

```
with open('OriginalFile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    emailreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    with open('text.txt','w') as output:
    for line in emailreader:
        output.write(line[1]+'\n')
```

Comment: why would op have better luck?

Comment: it shows just as many results, and instead of printing out just the emails from the csv file, it exports everything which is not what I want.

Comment: Also, use a single with block, separating the context managers with commas

Comment: Is that better @mad-physicist?

Comment: No, I meant that you should probably do `with open(..) as csvfile, open(...) as output:` and eliminate a level of nesting that way.